# C++ variable life time

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Below is an abstraction of what I am trying to do. The Main function calls **f1** and **f2** sequentially. In **f1**, it constructs a local variable **t**, and then calls a non-blocking function with **t**, where the **callback** captures a const reference of **t**. Before the **callback** gets executed, **f1** may have already returned, with **t** destroyed. I think in this case the **callback** would hold an invalid **t** when it is called. I write a test to mock the situation that **f2** finishes before the **callback** gets executed. It seems fine. Do I misunderstand anything about C++?

```
void Main() {
  f1();
  f2();
}

void f1() {
  T t(...);
  nonBlocking(t, Closure(callback, t));
}    

void callback(const T& t) {
  // do something with t
}

struct T {
  int* a;
  string* b;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe the code *happend* to work fine.

Comment: I wrote a test to mock that situation, where f2 finishes before the callback gets executed. It seems fine.

Comment: You're just getting lucky.  You're nonBlocking function is probably still seeing "T" because nothing else has overwriten it yet.  The destructor on t runs when it goes out of scope.  Anything could happen at that point.

Comment: If you make the destructor do something dramatic, like set a pointer to `NULL`, you have a better chance of showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, your understanding is correct. The reason you have to avoid bugs like this is that they make the code unpredictable. You've demonstrated this by failing to be able to predict the behavior of the code, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The code may appear to work fine, but that's really just an illusion that may shatter at any moment.

What happens is that T exists on the stack. Once f1 returns, that space is free and can be used for something else. Using the dangling reference after this point is undefined behaviour, and while that may mean it works occasionally, it may also mean it will randomly fail in any way it feels like.

In other words, don't do this.

Comment: I like this answer because it hints a little more clearly at why it may work fine sometimes.  When `t` falls out of scope and is destroyed, for many types of `T` (read: POD types) and for many compilers / optimization settings, the destruction is a no-op.  Therefore, if nothing writes over that location in memory, the reference captured in the callback looks like it's still pointing at the valid `t` value.  Of course, once you make your program any more complicated, nasty bugs are likely to arise here.

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion, just shouting "undefined behaviour", while technically correct, really doesn't help much in terms of understanding, and in the end the machine is still deterministic so while the language may not be defining any kind of behaviour, the machine certainly will. As a consequence, despite the hideous threat of UB, things may actually just work... Until something changes (and it may not be anything you expect) and things stop working. Explaining why this happens is likely to help people understand what's going on, and why they shouldn't be doing it.